# How to scroll scrollView on keyboard shown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I have a scrollView and ConstraintLayout as a child. Inside the constraintLayout, I have at least 2 editTexts.
My layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:focusable="false">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_with_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sendScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nextButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/endGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/startGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/exchangeCardView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/currency_switch_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/currency_switch_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ExchangeCurrencyView
                android:id="@+id/exchangeSwitchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amountEditText"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_x2"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/exchangeCardView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
            style="@style/AmountTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amountEditText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balanceTextView"
            style="@style/AddressTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amountTextView" />

        <SidedEditTextView
            android:id="@+id/walletAddressEditTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/balanceTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miningFeesTextView"
            style="@style/AddressTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/feesColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/walletAddressEditTextView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    style="@style/RoundButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin_x1"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:text="@string/send"
    android:translationZ="@dimen/elevation"
    app:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/endGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/startGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sendScrollView" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/startGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/endGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.94" />
```

I would like to scroll to the bottom of my scrollView in order to see all inputs above the button.

I used a KeyboardHeightProvider to to do this and it works :

```
override fun onHeightChanged(height: Int) {
    getScrollView()?.let {
        when (height) {
            0 -> {
                it.post {
                    it.scrollTo(0, 0)
                    onHide()
                }
            }
            else -> {
                it.post {
                    it.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with this snippet, the keyboard is blinking on screen and I get IInputConnectionWrapper warning.

I tried many other solutions like adding adjustPan or adjustResize but none worked.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Also, I used this :

```
val rootView = view?.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)?.getChildAt(0)
    rootView?.let {
        it.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val diff = it.rootView.height - it.height
            if (diff > dpToPx(context!!, 200F)) {
                sendScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
            } else {
                sendScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea?